# Adding values in a tuple that is in a list in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I retrieve some data from a database which returns it in a list of tuple values such as this: [(1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,)]

Is there a function that can sum up the values in the list of tuples? For example, the above sample should return 18.

Comment: You could use the SUM function directly in the database query (if supported).

Comment: Are they always `(1,)`, you could just use `len` :)

Comment: Thanks for that info AndiDog, I forgot about that function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> l = [(1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,)]
>>> s = sum(i[0] for i in l)
>>> print s
18
```

Comment: what if the tuples have numbers more than 1 digit? it wouldnt matter would it?

Comment: If they have more than one digit in a single number, it'll work fine. If they have more than one number, go with S.Mark's answer.

Answer (score 7):

```
>>>> l=[(1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,)]

>>> sum(map(sum,l))
18

>>> l[0]=(1,2,3,)
>>> l
[(1, 2, 3), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,)]
>>> sum(map(sum,l))
23
```

Answer (score 0):

Just some fun with itertools, not very readable.  Works only if you consider 1st element in tuple.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = [(1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (1,)]
>>> sum(*itertools.izip(*l))
18
```